# Difference between [T], &[T]

Tags: string, rust, slice

I want to know the difference between a `slice ([T])` and a `reference to a slice (&[T])`. I do not get how `slices` are unsized types, can't the compiler deduce the size of a slice through the source code?

I understand we need a reference to a slice to make it useful however, this would only make sense If I understand how `slices` are unsized.

Moreover, I wanted to know the difference between `str` and `&str`. I know one is a slice and the other is a reference to a slice and that `&str` stores a reference to the start of the string and the length as well. But it confuses me as to why we can't use `str` alone without the reference. Why can't we store the size within the `str` slice itself. Why do we need a reference to it. I come from a c++ background so maybe using c++ types and terminologies can clear things up!

Answer (score 6):

The reference, `&[T]` or `&str` is just a pointer (and a length). Where does this pointer point at? It points at some data. This data is the `[T]` (or `str`), the slice itself, the actual bytes of the data. There is no correspondance to that in C++.

Since the data can be of any length, there is no much we can do with `[T]`. We cannot take it as a parameter, we cannot return it, it *always* has to be wrapped with some kind of reference. Usually it's `&` or `&mut`, but it can also be `Box` or `Rc` or `Arc`, for owned slices.

Sometimes, the compiler could infer the slice size (e.g. when we're slicing via a closed constant range). But a slice type never encodes the length. Only a reference to it does, at runtime. This is because it is useful to have some data that can be of any runtime-determined length, like C++'s `std::span` or `std::string_view`.

Comment: How is a slice type itself represented in memory. I know how the reference to a slice is represented in memory but how is the slice itself represented. Could you also explain how a `owned` slice is referenced in memory and what benefits a owned slice provides.

Comment: @HumblePenguin A slice is just contiguous bytes interpreted as repeat of a type. It's like an array but of unknown length. And the benefit of an owned array is not having a lifetime, so it can be freely passed around and saved for later, like with any owned type (`Box<T>` vs `&mut T`).

Comment: I would rephrase that last comment saying that in memory a slice is just identical to an array of the same length. The difference between a slice and an array is that for the latter the length is part of its type; while for the former, the length is erased from the type and unknown to the compiler.

Comment: shoudn't this line of code:
`let slic = arr[..3];` create a copy of the array `arr` from the first element up till the second one. Instead I get a error telling me that it is unsized.

Comment: @HumblePenguin No, because indexing into array creates a slice, even if the index is a constant closed range.

Comment: Why do I need the borrow symbol to create a slice here? I mean I know slices are unsized types however we can clearly see the size here. And what does `Box<[T]>` actually mean? Am I storing a dynamically sized array of type T on the heap or am I storing a slice?

Comment: @HumblePenguin But this is the point: indexing using a range _always_ produces a slice, even when the size could be known at compile time, because this is how it is defined (and because indexing to array only when the size is known at compile-time will be confusing and hard to do).

Comment: @HumblePenguin And for `Box<[T]>`, you can look on it as dynamically-sized non-growable array on the heap, similar to `Box<[T; N]>` but dynamically sized, or similar to `Vec<T>` but that cannot grow. Or you can look on it as the owned version of `&[T]`. By Rust terminology, you're storing a slice because this is the type you have, but you can call it an array if that works better for you.

Comment: `arr[1..3]` return a slice. However as you said slices have a unknown size at compile time and can only be used through a pointer. My question is how does the slice it self look like? The pointer that points to it has a memory location to the beginning of the slice and as well as the length. However let's assume we did not need a pointer to access a unsized slice and that we could access a slice directly using it's bare type. How would the slice be stored in memory then? Would it be a copy of the array of still refer to the original array

Comment: @HumblePenguin It will be one `T`, then immediately after it another `T`, and this is all part of `arr` - that is, their memory is overlapping (the slice is the second and third elements in the array, and they're both in the slice and in the array).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254157/discussion-between-humble-penguin-and-chayim-friedman).